# Is it possible to read geoJSON or topoJSON file in R to draw a choropleth map?

Tags: r, geojson, topojson

`topoJSON` and `geoJSON` files are know very common for drawing maps on the internet. Is it possible to import them in `R` to draw choropleth maps?

Comment: Have you tried the `rJSON` package?

Comment: @vrajs5 Please use `code markdown` only for code, not for parts of sentences like "choropleth maps".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Get the `rgdal` package installed. Then if:

```
library(rgdal)
> "GeoJSON" %in% ogrDrivers()$name
[1] TRUE
```

then you can do something like:

```
> map = readOGR("foo.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
> plot(map)
```

But you need GeoJSON support in your `ogrDrivers` list.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if its possible to add new formats such as topojson to the ogrDrivers list ?

Comment: That's a two step process. For a brand new format, it has to be implemented in C or C++ as a "driver" for the underlying GDAL/OGR library. Secondly it has to be compiled into the GDAL/OGR library binary on your system. There is a topojson driver from GDAL 1.11 (according to wikipedia). If you dont see that then you need to upgrade some things on your machine.