# Determine what geoJSON polygon a point is in

Tags: r, geojson

I have two data frames, one that contains lat / long points and another that contains geojson data to draw multiple polygons.

The first dataframe (countyDF) is imported from a CSV and the 2nd dataframe (basinData) is imported from geoJSON using readLines()  (should I be using getJSON() instead for the json data?

i.e. (Over simplified lat and long, let me know if a more realistic example would help)
countyDF

```
pointNum Lat Long
1        100 251    
2        150 175
3        50  -330
4       -150 100
```

and geoJSON formatted like this(basinData):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },

"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Basin_ID": "9-19", "Basin_Subb": "9-19", "Basin_Name": "TIA JUANA", "Subbasin_N": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -117.0679768595155, 32.574291366336219 ], [ -117.06716593683379, 32.573400317874729 ], [ -117.06341997467541, 32.569091397019029 ], [ -117.06194315333148, 32.566356289257612 ], [ -117.0590009947062, 32.565022113434004 ], [ -117.05426277324793, 32.561991889800737 ], [ -117.04796901017907, 32.559156827796407 ], [ -117.03949416454982, 32.555722526353854 ], [ -117.03658670964059, 32.55260623337746 ], [ -117.03547505795123, 32.551186682532702 ], [ -117.03106791328587, 32.547633284977714 ], [ -117.02453341519558, 32.542766715943806 ], [ -117.03096733611001, 32.542203418941845 ], [ -117.0324558562139, 32.542073586201752 ], [ -117.03444148063983, 32.541897693349327 ], [ -117.03508530679723, 32.541840746762325 ], [ -117.03893675722108, 32.541503138385245 ], [ -117.04563848478635, 32.540916090254136 ], [ -117.04690666072744, 32.540805072734159 ], [ -117.04975321345368, 32.540555662782488 ], [ -117.05487638996065, 32.540105955834157 ], [ -117.05619151994331, 32.539990441256123 ], [ -117.05848531771566, 32.539788923486533 ], [ -117.0631749250457, 32.54215137136817 ], [ -117.06680187749691, 32.543877383980934 ], [ -117.06927539222501, 32.545562859775892 ], [ -117.07152258989198, 32.546046045900979 ], [ -117.07489884859852, 32.54530496670057 ], [ -117.07773834685484, 32.54485919550919 ], [ -117.0794889459513, 32.544200153274701 ], [ -117.08117134135811, 32.543542769155188 ], [ -117.08203266401881, 32.542495002174064 ], [ -117.08180018990477, 32.541005184972832 ], [ -117.07878527133475, 32.53800290854668 ], [ -117.08430738067622, 32.537515913009408 ], [ -117.08445861115598, 32.541710736294391 ], [ -117.08701141119104, 32.543969332906386 ], [ -117.08926545491882, 32.544796327561301 ], [ -117.09253292944108, 32.545435592907872 ], [ -117.09470680391962, 32.545631754871643 ], [ -117.09647622272129, 32.545948915009404 ], [ -117.09856416256312, 32.545227266049267 ], [ -117.10023514667088, 32.543994836689315 ], [ -117.10068933038696, 32.542953304281674 ], [ -117.09977208759979, 32.541129535758976 ], [ -117.09846043769052, 32.539943208794561 ], [ -117.09742346564566, 32.538925042182839 ], [ -117.0947242456092, 32.536597809766022 ], [ -117.09829488087858, 32.536282964307077 ], [ -117.09840179566876, 32.536275072973709 ], [ -117.10107619525394, 32.538466493837575 ], [ -117.10364734517533, 32.538196700466642 ], [ -117.10522233351519, 32.538976382033773 ], [ -117.10697118628674, 32.538259847181273 ], [ -117.10895422266631, 32.535344375464277 ], [ -117.11407862537365, 32.537631294453931 ], [ -117.11625581912718, 32.537999378719483 ], [ -117.11827996690573, 32.537508348187259 ], [ -117.11981739848021, 32.536392491701257 ], [ -117.11950653557783, 32.534417856408112 ], [ -117.12372820778141, 32.534103225208959 ], [ -117.12463878866241, 32.534032917908206 ], [ -117.12483027265007, 32.538135448497222 ], [ -117.12502048372495, 32.539350678974635 ], [ -117.12507499529305, 32.540448930323947 ], [ -117.12528896501055, 32.54199741245435 ], [ -117.12534718931569, 32.542421432291746 ], [ -117.12599067680821, 32.544551370001955 ], [ -117.12618141788914, 32.545696646353761 ], [ -117.12645239828784, 32.546429360119511 ], [ -117.12685554422104, 32.548102449008979 ], [ -117.12737138919654, 32.549703348943893 ], [ -117.12763885987745, 32.550533107582829 ], [ -117.12774693079939, 32.550626279391835 ], [ -117.12774760184091, 32.550738637890753 ], [ -117.12880070942489, 32.553488055429675 ], [ -117.13066553380129, 32.556444612620524 ], [ -117.13079138058607, 32.556859005175724 ], [ -117.13090941562115, 32.557248309210252 ], [ -117.13144943066766, 32.558277136765511 ], [ -117.1318548691015, 32.55947068448608 ], [ -117.13255675068075, 32.56215226422006 ], [ -117.13271798929109, 32.563505590313213 ], [ -117.13279809835319, 32.563664669666316 ], [ -117.13291972036119, 32.564513801799826 ], [ -117.13304092465259, 32.565358954253092 ], [ -117.13317600342353, 32.566483563557291 ], [ -117.13322866985202, 32.568729809322086 ], [ -117.13322781196094, 32.569368502964551 ], [ -117.13308936989753, 32.57249315647227 ], [ -117.13300847391125, 32.57431809617708 ], [ -117.13308839881873, 32.575694177896445 ], [ -117.13327826763549, 32.576450195841588 ], [ -117.13316931636456, 32.57809929670556 ], [ -117.12945373702573, 32.577489321400627 ], [ -117.12803166530341, 32.577626667375966 ], [ -117.12613400930002, 32.577713895283864 ], [ -117.1215685168029, 32.576694287394176 ], [ -117.11623399545566, 32.574537576560076 ], [ -117.11386955416937, 32.575034406011433 ], [ -117.11190978595226, 32.575409504886181 ], [ -117.10647756024149, 32.575149662771501 ], [ -117.10010384262075, 32.575306669257621 ], [ -117.09510331040457, 32.576303242644421 ], [ -117.09115860317613, 32.575789876157522 ], [ -117.08924842286103, 32.575244771913034 ], [ -117.08413987452015, 32.574174428676862 ], [ -117.0780854909149, 32.573290881813598 ], [ -117.07518693202192, 32.574254743186088 ], [ -117.07241851206417, 32.574928753914364 ], [ -117.0679768595155, 32.574291366336219 ] ] ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Basin_ID": "9-18", "Basin_Subb": "9-18", "Basin_Name": "OTAY VALLEY", "Subbasin_N": null }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -117.09094993890868, 32.619563585315568 ], [ -117.09024988989258, 32.616130450534968 ], [ -117.08912052342582, 32.606956836308925 ], [ -117.08936013555311, 32.601840287378998 ], [ -117.08875364427725, 32.598575478052986 ], [ -117.08680278644947, 32.595962898606246 ], [ -117.08441502669503, 32.595310423365085 ], [ -117.08156822333883, 32.595469231360795 ], [ -117.07566674287644, 32.595559902113109 ], [ -117.06972154230749, 32.596914588847568 ], [ -117.06432122834885, 32.598375496484095 ], [ -117.05964154380946, 32.598503627441907 ], [ -117.05616095566411, 32.597465378923445 ], [ -117.05457753753359, 32.596282762027229 ], [ -117.05073717232032, 32.594157791168556 ], [ -117.04589484061222, 32.592852213251177 ], [ -117.04312260910274, 32.593353146236865 ], [ -117.03899112955028, 32.593759832413419 ], [ -117.03371516847811, 32.59464309052418 ], [ -117.02862864592969, 32.594776592758308 ], [ -117.02272717085718, 32.594863862255089 ], [ -117.0174198657681, 32.594081171207122 ], [ -117.01427902225983, 32.593035965218846 ], [ -117.01229182668048, 32.591973496787411 ], [ -117.00991124266857, 32.59166411636609 ], [ -117.00874224342975, 32.590819514563513 ], [ -117.00439778679819, 32.59071141973822 ], [ -116.99862263551589, 32.590278958905216 ], [ -116.99501811309899, 32.589814373506385 ], [ -116.99227778615513, 32.588360796763084 ], [ -116.9878300187743, 32.586300314735269 ], [ -116.98294017247588, 32.586026512778012 ], [ -116.97812890271364, 32.586325564277786 ], [ -116.97467386624824, 32.586605260066648 ], [ -116.97337558327038, 32.586106965024619 ], [ -116.97141803299374, 32.586652564095417 ], [ -116.96871423244761, 32.587208317388864 ], [ -116.96622438005944, 32.588335212493227 ], [ -116.96042390526929, 32.590256368604443 ], [ -116.95557273144384, 32.592164131117251 ], [ -116.95221499420181, 32.594107400176057 ], [ -116.94872755550411, 32.596397127940342 ], [ -116.9459745479417, 32.59804505057086 ], [ -116.94404991193704, 32.60048471476123 ], [ -116.94239254000078, 32.602691044509697 ], [ -116.94129817998231, 32.602189536366552 ], [ -116.93999093720781, 32.601173820492207 ], [ -116.9387687523143, 32.601133484218465 ], [ -116.93659488322565, 32.600992021811464 ], [ -116.93460813321069, 32.599928207546924 ], [ -116.93113424649738, 32.599173132290474 ], [ -116.9290142367999, 32.598225880469577 ], [ -116.9297423527787, 32.597181836096283 ], [ -116.93156090942639, 32.596409563977744 ], [ -116.93419840172811, 32.59591322458288 ], [ -116.93526867881214, 32.59503617591411 ], [ -116.93605726039273, 32.593589412189353 ], [ -116.93802757033967, 32.593733854613859 ], [ -116.94108823292062, 32.59415039913921 ], [ -116.94387352503604, 32.59434074502488 ], [ -116.94622507549801, 32.593043461784966 ], [ -116.94952443572129, 32.591618310534955 ], [ -116.95503847459827, 32.588839924862008 ], [ -116.96069206495801, 32.586289312384324 ], [ -116.96744074207328, 32.584296717135018 ], [ -116.97352519139275, 32.58311772322412 ], [ -116.981310419243, 32.58220119915768 ], [ -116.98674868342913, 32.582811874361674 ], [ -116.98884496772166, 32.58243634623561 ], [ -116.99120624064994, 32.581712707774301 ], [ -116.99562328744466, 32.582107923888408 ], [ -117.00194664640887, 32.582877158297073 ], [ -117.0089538927989, 32.583923150362544 ], [ -117.01141157202515, 32.584748556651512 ], [ -117.01434837489472, 32.585796911898029 ], [ -117.01815538476318, 32.586200321663206 ], [ -117.02285874709682, 32.587394380373176 ], [ -117.02575839115465, 32.586431974986255 ], [ -117.02839270252196, 32.585818237773253 ], [ -117.03196930799476, 32.584788393166896 ], [ -117.0353541393241, 32.584393233527791 ], [ -117.03987787273692, 32.583234126182219 ], [ -117.04456223839728, 32.583393332527173 ], [ -117.05183697612944, 32.584203049689997 ], [ -117.05593610914512, 32.585692117192636 ], [ -117.06281865949224, 32.587253753081214 ], [ -117.06796448881572, 32.58671587048164 ], [ -117.07223334682625, 32.58642076677404 ], [ -117.07703883952287, 32.585830015255262 ], [ -117.08162775469272, 32.584553520964334 ], [ -117.08146648913291, 32.583234519028593 ], [ -117.08023020967258, 32.582449325419546 ], [ -117.07885455120608, 32.581493901980991 ], [ -117.07727361062912, 32.580426941222797 ], [ -117.07425083808856, 32.578462550566684 ], [ -117.06938355028353, 32.575836820265927 ], [ -117.0679768595155, 32.574291366336219 ], [ -117.07241851206417, 32.574928753914364 ], [ -117.07518693202192, 32.574254743186088 ], [ -117.0780854909149, 32.573290881813598 ], [ -117.08413987452015, 32.574174428676862 ], [ -117.08924842286103, 32.575244771913034 ], [ -117.09115860317613, 32.575789876157522 ], [ -117.09510331040457, 32.576303242644421 ], [ -117.10010384262075, 32.575306669257621 ], [ -117.10647756024149, 32.575149662771501 ], [ -117.11190978595226, 32.575409504886181 ], [ -117.11386955416937, 32.575034406011433 ], [ -117.11623399545566, 32.574537576560076 ], [ -117.1215685168029, 32.576694287394176 ], [ -117.12613400930002, 32.577713895283864 ], [ -117.12803166530341, 32.577626667375966 ], [ -117.12945373702573, 32.577489321400627 ], [ -117.13316931636456, 32.57809929670556 ], [ -117.1331563833194, 32.580461353063633 ], [ -117.13313895151131, 32.583667037314477 ], [ -117.13305735034756, 32.583895362177643 ], [ -117.13302977296665, 32.585640269688504 ], [ -117.13295680012118, 32.588445797309987 ], [ -117.13289081976185, 32.590978124650832 ], [ -117.13297029012178, 32.593220472898004 ], [ -117.13327298374499, 32.596429216273556 ], [ -117.13369223287799, 32.600867834211961 ], [ -117.12357324390332, 32.599849353180694 ], [ -117.11589749104179, 32.600462415367865 ], [ -117.1158318107198, 32.599777199361775 ], [ -117.11569656396389, 32.599570329888948 ], [ -117.11357898780251, 32.600647416312967 ], [ -117.11177228173005, 32.601566355813603 ], [ -117.11086691646757, 32.6021189358108 ], [ -117.109148177021, 32.60316887609109 ], [ -117.10657781402381, 32.605005474819528 ], [ -117.10440205308318, 32.606810459053861 ], [ -117.10381630211057, 32.607296700104691 ], [ -117.10324926304537, 32.607915653098537 ], [ -117.1011662702258, 32.612340439524345 ], [ -117.10075972866082, 32.612638859150657 ], [ -117.09977514995659, 32.61283800452685 ], [ -117.09894626905405, 32.613005656528017 ], [ -117.09840512482522, 32.613004595665437 ], [ -117.09740410874794, 32.613049694419168 ], [ -117.09705139513309, 32.613600174933183 ], [ -117.09705183800251, 32.613714871347049 ], [ -117.09843269412127, 32.614767877138462 ], [ -117.09843275610504, 32.615089758769592 ], [ -117.09764747762975, 32.616740386051163 ], [ -117.09756685742629, 32.617197966049851 ], [ -117.09758669043111, 32.617689185373024 ], [ -117.09759495313509, 32.617885380739892 ], [ -117.09783823577867, 32.618045356304386 ], [ -117.09794643605798, 32.618320326264303 ], [ -117.09786566853079, 32.619785920093079 ], [ -117.09094993890868, 32.619563585315568 ] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

I want to test point numbers 1,2,3,4 against all "Basin_ID"'s and if they are within that basin, add that as a column to countyDF.

For example if point 1 were in basin 9-18 and none of the other points fell within polygons contained in basinData the returned data frame would look like the following...

returnedDF:

```
pointNum Lat Long   Basin
1        100 251    9-18
2        150 175     n/a
3        50  -330    n/a
4       -150 100     n/a
```

Might anybody suggest a specific library / method / solution of accomplishing this?  I imagine if there's a library that tests if a point is in a polygod I can loop over the 2nd dataframe for each point?

Comment: @hrbrmstr  As far as I know, `over` is from the `sp` package ;)

Comment: `sp::point.in.polygon()` / `sp::over()` – hrbrmstr 16 hours ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it, using `rgdal` to read the geojson ([see this answer for more details on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24183007/is-it-possible-to-read-geojson-or-topojson-file-in-r-to-draw-a-choropleth-map)) and `sp` and/or `rgeos` to test if a point lies within a polygon or not.

Note, I adjusted your coordinates, since none of them was located within a polygon.

First, read the data:

```
countyDF <- read.table(textConnection("
pointNum Lat Long
1        32.6 -117.1    
2        90 175
4       -90 100"), header = TRUE)


basinDF <- rgdal::readOGR("basin.json", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

Make sure points and polygons have the same projection:

```
sp::coordinates(countyDF) <- ~Long+Lat
sp::proj4string(countyDF) <- sp::proj4string(basinDF)
```

Here we use `sp::over` to extract the attributes of `basinDF` at each point. If points are not located within a polygon of `basinDF` `NA` is returned.

```
sp::over(countyDF, basinDF)

# Basin_ID Basin_Subb  Basin_Name Subbasin_N
#  1     9-18       9-18 OTAY VALLEY       <NA>
#  2     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
#  3     <NA>       <NA>        <NA>       <NA>
```

Alternatively, you could also use `rgeos`, which tells you that point 1 is located in poygon 1.

```
rgeos::gWithin(countyDF, basinDF, byid = TRUE)

#   1     2     3
# 0 FALSE FALSE FALSE
# 1  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This accomplished what I was trying to do, I just used a cbind at the end to line the basins back up with the original points.  I.e. point 1, lat, long, basin id, basin sub, basin name etc. in one data frame.  Thank you!